# Custom share provider for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to add a service to the "share providers". For example when you share a page in IE via Facebook, e-mail oder text messages.

I want to add a custom one, so I can save these in my Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Windows 8 allows you something similar via its [new sharing mechanism](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/Windows-Share), but WP7 does not have this functionality.